# Hadoop "error while writing TokenizerMapper permission denied"

Tags: java, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Developer Console for running the Hadoop example "WordCount". The error I am getting when I run `hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java` is:

```
WordCount.java:26: error: error while writing TokenizerMapper: 
WordCount$TokenizerMapper.class (Permission denied)
public static class TokenizerMapper
```

There is an arrow pointing to class of the last line.
`echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH` returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar`
`echo $HADOOP_HOME` returns `/home/hadoop/hadoop-install` 
`echo $JAVA_HOME` returns  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre`
`javac -version` returns `javac 1.6.0_36` 
`java -version` returns `java version "1.6.0_36"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.8) (6b36-1.13.8-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

I changed the permissions on the javac file to be 777 and WordCount.java  but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a terrible work around and I do not recommend it but I changed the permission of the /home/hadoop directory to 777 and it works. I couldn't find where TokenizedMapper resided in my user file. This is a terrible option but I am accepting it in order to close the question

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who had made hadoop installation with creating different hadoop user, make sure that your WordCount.java file also resides in the same hadoop installation directory (in my case "/usr/local/hadoop/"). Otherwise Hadoop will not get permission to access that java file.

Answer (score 0):

compile it as root if not working you have to giving correctly and securely root privileges to your hadoop user 
you can do it by editing the /etc/sudoers